# how to use gpu and cpu compute at the same time?

Tags: cuda

Is it possible to use multicore cpu and gpu (on one computer) to compute at the same time and dynamically schedule workloads? What is the interface between cpu and gpu code?

Any beginner referrence? Thanks

Comment: why down vote? I think this is a legitimate question. Please give your reason for down voting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPU and GPU process at the same time by default unless you (explicitly or implicitly) apply a synchronization instruction. In CUDA, which I'm assuming your platform of interest is, conversation between CPU and GPU are mostly confined to synchronization instructions, kernel launch instruction, and most importantly global memory. In discrete GPUs, they communicate by means of global memory.

About dynamically scheduling, there is a lot of work in literature. GPUs are best when they receive the data they want to work on in bulk, process it, and deliver the outcome back to host (CPU side). When it comes to dynamic scheduling, it's most of the time costly unless you are sure the load you're sending to GPU to process is worth it.

You might want to google and investigate about AMD APUs, which have CPU and GPUs on the same die. I heard they are more flexible in terms of dynamic work scheduling because address space is physically the same and CPU<->GPU communication is not that costly.

About the reference for beginners, I started with **CUDA by Example** written by *Jason Sanders* and *Edward Kandrot*. I found it very good to begin. But beware that the book doesn't (and can't) cover some important topics. And since the book is written, new generations of CUDA devices with novel features have been introduced by NVIDIA. Have an eye on online resources too.

Good luck!